# How can I change WebUI interface port 8080 for RethinkDB on Linux?

Tags: rethinkdb

I'm running RethinkDB on Amazon Linux AMI. I already have services running on 8080 so I need to change the port for the WebUI interface. How would I do that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I happen to find the documentation here https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/cli-options/

```
$ rethinkdb --bind all --http-port 9090
```

Answer (score 2):

Karthick here has the right answer if you are running your instance of RethinkDB from the command line and daemonizing it.

In case you are running the default system configuration of RethinkDB after say `sudo apt-get install rethinkdb` and want to change it there you have to change the configuration file by following these steps:

You want to look under the directory `/etc/rethinkdb` and find the RethinkDB configuration file and change the `http-port` value to the new port you'd like it to be on.

Then if your system uses `init.d` you should be able to restart with `sudo service rethinkdb restart. If your system uses`systemd`then you'll do something like this`sudo systemctl [restart|stop/start] rethinkdb`

These two links will be a good resource to you in this case:

- https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/config-file/
- https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/start-on-startup/